# Jquery and Javascript validation crashing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, onblur

So I already have some validation working on the individual blanks onblur, but they simply display a message, they do not stop the form from being processed.  I decided to try to record whether or not the validations had been passed using a variable "validationError", but now every time I submit the form the site freezes and crashes.  Is there a better way to do this?  The onblur error message still works.

relevant js in document ready function:

```
$("#studentEmail").blur(function() {
            $(".studentEmailError").empty();
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            email1Value = $(this).val()     
            if(!emailReg.test($(this).val())) {
                $(".studentEmailError").html('Please enter a valid email');
                validationError = "true";
            }
            else {
            validationError="false";
            }
        });




$(".submit").click(function() {  

    if (validationError == "true") {
    return false;
    }

    else if (validationError == "false"){
    //PROCESS INFORMATION
    }
```

Comment: Nothing there looks like it could crash it.  Have you tried seeing if Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's developer tools are telling you of any errors?  Also, using "true" and "false" instead of boolean true and false makes no sense.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, i'd recommend to use one of the validation plugins <http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/>. Agree with Corbin. Just tried on jsfiddle - doesn't crash.

Comment: hmmm I wonder what is going wrong then.  I've been playing with it using the changes from the answer below, and now the form isn't returning false.  I'm just going to look through it again to see if I can find a typo then I can post an update.  I didn't want to use the validation plugin because I was having a hard time getting it to work onblur.

Comment: I test it in jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ijse/HBTRh/, it didn't crash or froze.

Comment: Instead of crashing, it should show an alert box that says that the query was good.  Also, I am pretty new at this, and I'm not that familiar with Firebug (though I do have it).  I'll go look up a couple tutorials.

Comment: I think I am going to have to find a new way to do this.  Something is conflicting.  With all the changes from this page, it is only crashing in Chrome, but ie and ff still are not processing the form.  Maybe I could use the plugin in conjunction with the onblur still I already have, it just seems heavy to use two forms of validation.

Answer (score 1):

It might be crashing because you are missing a semicolon on this line:

```
email1Value = $(this).val()
```

You also shouldn't use string values as a "boolean". Simply set your variables to the boolean value:

```
validationError = true;
```

then you can just do:

```
if(validationError){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Semi-colons are optional in JavaScript.  They should never be omitted, but they technically can be, and the parser pretends there is one at the next line break.

Comment: @flyfish: Your first point isn't valid because JavaScript inserts missing semicolons. That's only an issue with return statements.  I agree with the second point that true/false shouldn't be represented as strings.

Comment: These changes didn't stop the freezing.  Also, the final change was causing a page refresh instead of a return false (which also happens if validation error == false)